# SQL comparison returns wrong result in WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, cpanel

I am using MariaDB in cPanel.
I have a DB with a few tables and a few views.

Let's say we have a view called `v_1`.
If you `SELECT * FROM v_1` it returns two columns (`cell_a` and `cell_b`):

```
-------------------------
| cell_a   |   cell_b   |
>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<
-------------------------
|  hello   |     a      |
-------------------------
|   good   |    NULL    |
-------------------------
|    bye   |    NULL    |
-------------------------
|   word   |     b      |
-------------------------
```

Type of the `cell_a` is `char`(6) and `cell_b` is `varchar(1)`.

Then I am trying to fetch data from a view, using a simple statement:

```
SELECT * FROM view_name WHERE cell_b = 'a';
```

But it returns an empty response.

If I try:

```
SELECT LENGTH(cell_b) as len FROM view_name;
```

it responds with:

```
------
| len |
=======
|  1  |
-------
|  0  |
-------
|  0  |
-------
|  1  |
-------
```

Which is right.

Ok, then, I am trying this:

```
SELECT * FROM v_1 WHERE LENGTH(cell_b) = 1;
```

And receive an empty response again.

But if I try:

```
SELECT * FROM v_1 WHERE LENGTH(cell_b) = 0;
```

It returns a table with 2 rows, where cell_b is empty.

Then I tried:

1. `LIKE 'a'`
2. `LIKE '%a%'`
3. and `REGEXP 'a'` and this only **works**.

**UPDATE 1:**
I have removed and re-created all the indexes in every table.
Then, I recreated the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE table_new LIKE table;
INSERT INTO table_new SELECT * FROM table;
RENAME TABLE table TO crushed_table;
RENAME TABLE table_new TO table;
ANALYZE TABLE table;
```

and it did not work too.

**UPDATE 2:**
Tried to repair tables.

Also tried:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci;
```

Please help me find out why I cannot fetch the data with `SELECT * FROM v_1 WHERE cell_b = 'a'`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A fiddle would be great! https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6

Comment: Sounds like a broken index. Try to reindex the table

Comment: Thanks, @Jens. I will try now and reply.

Comment: @Jens unfortunately, it did not work. I am sorry. I will update my question with steps I came through.

Comment: What's the sql used in the view?